# dbus-send fails due to QDBusRawType

Tags: dbus

The introspection of the service returns the below for the method I'm interested in

```
method bool org.my.connectionInterface.sendParam(QDBusRawType::(is param))
```

However, when I try to send a message, I get this error

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.my.connectionInterface /Connection1 org.my.connectionInterface.sendParam int32:1 string:"jolly-string"

Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'sendParam' in interface 'org.my.connectionInterface' at object path '/Connection1' (signature 'is')
```

I can call the methods with no parameters or simple parameters types, so, I presume the issue is with QDBusRawType. Is there a way to wrap the parameters in QDBusRawType?

Comment: What does the introspection XML look like?

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect `int32:` and `string:` to be required as the method has the signature of `is` so it knows that the first parameter is an `int32` and the second a `string`.

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.my.connectionInterface /Connection1 org.my.connectionInterface.sendParam 1 "jolly-string"
```

If that doesn't work, can you update your question with the output using:

```
busctl introspect SERVICE OBJECT [INTERFACE]
```